# Add two variables in javascript efficiently

Tags: javascript

Is there an efficient way to add two variables `a` and `b` when they could be dynamic? I also need to check if their types are numbers. I think the way I have described below is not the best/modern way to implement this. Please help.

**EDIT**

I also want to make sure if one the variable is not a number(or `null`) then the variable `C` gets its value from the variable which is the number . How can I do it?

```
const a;
const b;
let c;

// variables a and b are dynamic and could be null.
if(typeOf(a)==='number' && typeOf(b)==='number'){

if(!a && b){
c=b
}
if(a && !b){
c=a
}
if(a && b){
c=a+b
}

}
```

Comment: Don't use `()` when using the typeof operator. Use `typeof a === ` etc. Also, it's lowercase.

Comment: What do you mean by "dynamic"? What values do you expect them to have?

Comment: Do you mean `null`, `0`, or `NaN`?

Comment: Dynamic as in ..it could be coming from a service. i expect them to be numbers but still want to check if they really are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply check with `typeof` and use the logical or operator to convert `NaN` to `0`.

```
if(typeof a ==='number' && typeof b === 'number'){
   c = (a || 0) + (b || 0);
}
```

To also allow invalid values to be treated as 0, you can use this:

```
c = (typeof a === 'number' ? (a || 0) : 0) + (typeof b === 'number' ? (b || 0) : 0)
```

It could also be written like so:

```
c = (typeof a === 'number' && !isNaN(a) ? a : 0) + (typeof b === 'number' && !isNaN(b) ? b : 0)
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219314/discussion-on-answer-by-hev1-add-two-variables-in-javascript-efficiently).

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for

```
const c = (typeof a == 'number' ? a : 0)
        + (typeof b == 'number' ? b : 0);
```